# Two docker installs on Ubuntu - snap and "standard"? How to remove one?

Tags: 20.04, docker

I had a fresh of install of Ubuntu 20.04 and got docker running somehow. I don't recall how, unfortunately. Maybe it was pre-installed. But, it worked as expected and stored volumes in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`

The application I was running was started with docker-compose.

Fast forward a few months, and I started working on a script to stop containers, back up the volume, and then restart the container. Around the same time, it turns out my system suddenly seems to have transitioned to using the snap version of docker. The volumes are now stored at `/var/snap/docker/common-var-lib-docker/volumes`.

My containers were suddenly showing no data - it was left behind in the old volume location.

Meanwhile, it seems like systemd still thinks it is controlling docker, but isn't. `sysctl stop docker` thinks it stops docker (confirmed by `sysctl status docker`) but the containers are actually still running.

I was able to bring my data over by copying the volumes to the snap location, but I want to clean up the mess.

How do I get this resolved so that I only have one docker binary/config, and systemd isn't confused?

Comment: Please see my answer in this question for a solution: [Docker containers running, but not showing up in docker ps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315822/docker-containers-running-but-not-showing-up-in-docker-ps)