# Docker taking too much space, even after removing all the images and containers

Tags: 22.04, filesystem, docker, storage

I started using Docker recently and Docker was taking up too much space even after i prune all the dangling containers and images.

When is try to run `sudo docker system prune --all -f` it shows `"container prune" requires API version 1.25, but the Docker daemon API version is 1.24` but clearly my Docker is at version 1.44When I run `sudo docker version`.

Every category is zero when I run `docker system df`.

I used Docker to spawn a Python container and installed libraries like Flask in it many times it also had the access to docker.sock to spawn new containers.

Is that taking up all the space?. If so, how to claim the space back?

Here's `sudo docker info` output

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    25.0.0
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2-desktop.5
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.23.0-desktop.1
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-dev
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.2.20
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-extension
  init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0-beta.9
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-init
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)
    Version:  0.6.0
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-sbom
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.26.0
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan
  scout: Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.0.9
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-scout

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.24
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc version: 
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.5.0-14-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu Core 22
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 20
 Total Memory: 15.24GiB
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Concerning the version issue, pls try updating docker compose first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538216/docker-client-api-version-issue

Comment: I think the version issue is because there's both a `.deb` and a `snap` version of Docker installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `docker info` command shows something "interesting" (read: wrong). It says:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    25.0.0
...
   Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

But then it says:

```
Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.24
 ...
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
```

Coincidently, the client version matches the latest version from Docker repos, but the server version matches the latest stable `snap` version of Docker.

This, combined with the given paths (one has `/usr/lib`, the other has `/var/snap`), leads me to believe that you have Docker installed as both a `snap` package and a normal `.deb` package from the Docker repos.

My suggestion is to remove the `snap` package, and then maybe reinstall Docker to make sure everything is OK.

```
sudo snap remove docker
sudo apt-get install --reinstall docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

Now I believe Docker should work correctly with only the latest version.

Also [see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315822/docker-containers-running-but-not-showing-up-in-docker-ps/), which is somewhat similar.

Comment: Yeah now docker is working the issue was the one you said but still after reinstalling docker and running the prune again, it still is taking  15.24GiB is there any way to free this space?

Comment: For disk space, please see if there are any files left inside `/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker`. If yes, those can now be removed.

Comment: You should probably write up a new question, describing the new situation and problem.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative reason: **user is not part of `docker` group**.

And `docker system prune` does not clearly state that, instead giving ambiguous `"container prune" requires API version 1.25, but the Docker daemon API version is 1.24` error

Add user to `docker` group or use `sudo`.

Comment: Are you sure? OP was already using `sudo`, so the group membership didn't matter for them. And if a user who's not in the docker group tried `docker system prune` without sudo, I'd actually expect to see an error involving the Docker daemon's socket `/var/run/docker.sock`. To even get to the API mismatch error they'd need to be able to access that socket, which wouldn't work without root or the docker group membership.

Comment: You are right, indeed, it works with `sudo` either way, just confirmed it.

However, without sudo it is as described - which tells that this error is most probably not a root cause, but ambigous message, when client seems to unable to contact the socket.

Comment: Or you, like OP have the Docker daemon installed in two different ways, and only when you don't have permissions for accessing one of them do you see the error about version mismatch.

Comment: `sudo` was exactly what I needed! Thanks!